# Proving that the Mobius strip cannot be retracted to its boundary.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was recently asked to prove that the Mobius strip cannot be retracted to a circle. My teacher offered the following argument:

Let the Mobius strip be $M$, and its boundary be $B$. Let $i:B\to M$ be the inclusion map, and $r: M\to B$ the retraction map. Then $r\circ i: B\to B$ is $\text{id}_B$, where $\text{id}_B$ stands for the identity on $B$. Hence, $r_*\circ i_*=id_{*_B}$. But $i_*(n)=2n$, and therefore $r_*(2)=1$, which is not a valid homomorphism.

Why is $r$ not a valid homomorphism if $r_*(2)=1$? I feel that it is a valid homomorphism, although it is not surjective, which contradicts the existence of the retraction.

Comment: What are the possible values of the element $2$ under a homomorphism $h\colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @DanRust- Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

If $r_{\ast}(2)=1$, then what is $r_{\ast}(1)$?